# Flutter - Accessing JSON nested array values

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am attempting to create a Flutter app that reads JSON data and outputs to a listview. Below I have typed out a short example of my data.

Currently I am grabbing my data using:

```
Future<String> getJsonData() async {
var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assests/data/test.json');

this.setState(() {
  var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response);
  data = convertDataToJson;
});
```

I am then outputting my data using:

```
child: new Text(data[index]['text'])
```

How do I output the name of the Manager object that is stored?

```
  _id: 397134856770953216
  text: "This is the text that is stored"
  Manager: Object
      uName: "Username"
      name: "Real Name"
  Client: Object
      uName:"Second Username"
      name:"Second Real Name"
```

Comment: No way to tell without seeing the content of `assests/data/test.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access it by:

```
String managerName = data['Manager']['uName'];
print(managerName);
```

It will work.